# Getting all request parameters in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, request

In symfony 2 controllers, every time I want to get a value from post I need to run:

```
$this->getRequest()->get('value1');
$this->getRequest()->get('value2');
```

Is there any way to consolidate these into one statement that would return an array? Something like Zend's getParams()?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can do `$this->getRequest()->query->all();` to get all GET params and `$this->getRequest()->request->all();` to get all POST params.

So in your case:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
$params['value1'];
$params['value2'];
```

For more info about the Request class, see http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

Comment: To get values for parameters in the path (eg /posts/{id}) use `$request->attributes->all()`. I was using `$request->get()` thinking that was the only way to get this data and came here looking for another way.

Answer (score 12):

With Recent Symfony 2.6+ versions as a best practice Request is passed as an argument with action in that case you won't need to explicitly call $this->getRequest(), but rather call $request->request->all()

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotAcceptableHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

    class SampleController extends Controller
    {


        public function indexAction(Request $request) {

           var_dump($request->request->all());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For **Symfony 3.4**, you can access the data for both **GET** and **POST**,
Like This

**Post**:

```
$data = $this->request->request->all();
```

**Get**:

```
$data = $this->request->query->all();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are in a controller, the action method is given a `Request` parameter.

You can access all POST data with `$request->request->all();`.
This returns a key-value pair array.

When using GET requests you access data using `$request->query->all();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, remember this is always PHP, so you could just check for the superglobal variable `$_REQUEST`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php